# FastReport: How to change number of shown decimal places of a datafield

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fastreport

For a client I have developed a T-SQL based customer report for calculation the number of working hours per day as as decimal (e.g. 0.5 for 30 min ..). These results are used for a FastReport (Version 3.2.). Currently decimal places are only shown if the calculated number has decimal digits.

Now I want to change the output to always showing 2 decimal digits (e.g. 2.00, 2.50) and if there are more decimal digits I want to show 5 decimal places (e.g. 2.33333).

For the formatstring of the field (showing my calculated working hours) I tried:

`%2,2f`

which works for the first case. And for 5 places:

`%2,5f`

But I don't know to dynamically change the format string depending on the number of digits (like hours%0.01 == 0 format string = %2,2f else %2,5f).

I also tried solving the problem on SQL Server 2017 level with:

```
CASE cdata % 0.01
    WHEN 0 THEN CAST(cdata AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    ELSE CAST(cdata AS DECIMAL(10,5))
END AS GesHour
```

and then printing "GesHour" as text. But this doesn't worked either.

It would be very kind if someone could help me.

Comment: Could you always assume 5 decimal places and trim off of they're zero?

Comment: A [`case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression can only return a single data type, including _scale_ and _precision_, following the rules for [data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You could use the [`format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function with a `case` expression for the `format` argument so that the result is always a string, e.g. `varchar(16)`.

Comment: Formatting cdata as `VARCHAR(16)` does the job:

`CASE cdata % 0.01 WHEN 0 THEN CAST(CAST(cdata AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS VARCHAR(16)) ELSE CAST(CAST(cdata AS DECIMAL(10,5)) AS VARCHAR(16)) END AS GesHour`       


Thanks for the hint.

Additionally, does someone knows how to solve this inside the FastReport?

Comment: @RE0 Use another expression as value of this `TfrxMemoView`. What is your programming language?